# How to retrieve preference data from the service

Tags: java, android, android-service, sharedpreferences, preferences

I m developing an android app.

The main activity  is a preferencescreen

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
```

my app contains also a `service` that start automatically when the android boot.

In the `onStart()` of my service class, I m trying to retrieve data saved by the user in the preferencescreen with the following code

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {     
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    get_prefrence_settings((Preference) preferences);
    jniTask = new JniBackGround();
    jniTask.execute(new String[] { "http://www.easycwmp.org" });
}

private void get_prefrence_settings(Preference p) {
    if (p instanceof PreferenceGroup) {
        PreferenceGroup pGrp = (PreferenceGroup) p;
        for (int i = 0; i < pGrp.getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
            get_prefrence_settings(pGrp.getPreference(i));
        }
    } else {
        if (p instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPref = (ListPreference) p;
            p.setSummary(listPref.getEntry());
            client_interface = (String) listPref.getEntry();
        }
        if (p instanceof CheckBoxPreference) {
            if (((TwoStatePreference) p).isChecked())
                enable = "1";
        }
        if (p instanceof EditTextPreference) {
            if (pref_key.equals("Time")) {
                time = editTextPref.getText();
            }
       }
    }
}
```

but I m getting a crash when my service start that indicate that:

```
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl can not be cast to android.preference.Preference
```

How to retrieve the preference settings from my `onStart()` service without loading the MainActivity interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to retrieve the preference settings from my onStart() service without loading the MainActivity interface?

Call `getString()`, `getInt()`, or related getter methods on [the `SharedPreferences` object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).